# Crear un array a partir de otro array?? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola estimados estoy tratando de crear un array N a partir de otro con estructuras diferentes
lo que estoy tratando de crear de un objeto base otro array

he intentado hacer de varias forma pero aún no llego al resultado deseado he llegado a este resultado pero para los demás no logro insertar ese nivel

Con este array base quiero llegar al que esta abajo

```
[
    {
        "suma": 262.34190216330126,
        "marca": "SKAND",
        "lstSubmenu": [
            {
                "seccion": "TORNILLOS",
                "lstSeccion": [
                    {
                        "categoria": "TORNILLO VOLCANITA CRS MADERA",
                        "suma": 37.41715341683438
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TORNILLO MADERA  ESTRUCTURAS (TURBO)",
                        "suma": 22.508639854731268
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TORNILLO VOLCANITA METAL",
                        "suma": 16.48031714561349
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "FULMINANTE VAINA ROJO AMARILLO CALIBRE .27",
                        "suma": 13.473193915399513
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "AUTOPERFORANTE TAPFAST TECHO MADERA",
                        "suma": 8.776999963607862
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TIRAFONDO HEXAGONAL MADERA",
                        "suma": 7.300000000000001
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TORNILLO CABEZA LENTEJA METAL",
                        "suma": 7.276133964067369
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "AUTOPERFORANTE HEXAGONAL METAL",
                        "suma": 7.045190446934608
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "AUTOPERFORANTE HEXAGONAL CON GOLILLA TECHO METAL",
                        "suma": 5.573167700273727
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "CLAVO DISPARO POLVORA SDM HORMIGON",
                        "suma": 1.5152119865873657
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TORNILLO MADERA MUEBLES",
                        "suma": 0.6049151332396524
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TORNILLO PARA FIBROCEMENTO",
                        "suma": 0.19929074105507238
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "ROSCALATA RANURA COMBINADA",
                        "suma": 0.046330078869591194
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TARUGO CLAVO HORMIGON",
                        "suma": 0.030332912614208018
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "GOLILLA PLANA",
                        "suma": 0.0033440822661030853
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "GOLILLA PRESION",
                        "suma": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "PERNO HEXAGONAL GRADO 2 UNC - ISO 5.8 METRICO",
                        "suma": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "PRODUCTOS CALZADOS                                ",
                        "suma": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "CLAVO ACERO HORMIGON",
                        "suma": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TARUGO HORMIGON",
                        "suma": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TORNILLO PARA HERRAJES",
                        "suma": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "seccion": "ABRASIVOS",
                "lstSeccion": [
                    {
                        "categoria": "DISCO CORTE ACERO",
                        "suma": 33.85791067578473
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "DISCO TRASLAPADO ACERO",
                        "suma": 6.806285061196529
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "DISCO DESBASTE ACERO",
                        "suma": 5.906160259171886
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "DISCO CORTE CONCRETO",
                        "suma": 4.119951452256649
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "COPA CORTE CONCRETO",
                        "suma": 1.1727751112538822
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "DISCO CORTE CERAMICA",
                        "suma": 0.4903814350895895
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "DISCO FUNDICION ACERO",
                        "suma": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "seccion": "SOLDADURA",
                "lstSeccion": [
                    {
                        "categoria": "ALAMBRE MIG SOLIDO  E70S-6",
                        "suma": 22.943545314549496
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "ELECTRODO AWS E6011",
                        "suma": 10.279470901277177
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "ELECTRODO AWS E7018",
                        "suma": 6.1487509484998295
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "ALAMBRE MIG TUBULAR E71T-1",
                        "suma": 3.1778677999999996
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "ELECTRODO AWS E6010",
                        "suma": 1.65330998985258
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "seccion": "TECLE",
                "lstSeccion": [
                    {
                        "categoria": "TIRACABLE-TIRFOR (Y-H)",
                        "suma": 8.970746389999999
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TECLE MANUAL CADENA HD (CHB)",
                        "suma": 4.592762842743909
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TECLE PALANCA CADENA HD (LHA)",
                        "suma": 3.754105505600121
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "GRILLETES",
                        "suma": 0.55551605
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "ESLINGAS PLANAS",
                        "suma": 0.21745942556541334
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "ESLINGAS TIRO AMARRE CARGAS",
                        "suma": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "TECLE ELECTRICO CADENA 1AM (EHB)",
                        "suma": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "categoria": "CADENA CARGA-MANDO",
                        "suma": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
             
             
        ]
    },
    
]
```

A este resultado quiero quiero llegar con el array de base que esta arriba

```
 [
    {
        "label": "SKAND",
        "url": "/shop/catalog",
        "menu": {
            "type": "megamenu",
            "size": "xl",
            "image": "assets/images/megamenu/megamenu-1.jpg",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "size": 3,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "label": "TORNILLOS",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "label": "TORNILLO VOLCANITA CRS MADERA",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "TORNILLO MADERA  ESTRUCTURAS (TURBO)",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "TORNILLO VOLCANITA METAL",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "FULMINANTE VAINA ROJO AMARILLO CALIBRE .27",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "AUTOPERFORANTE TAPFAST TECHO MADERA",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "TIRAFONDO HEXAGONAL MADERA",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "TORNILLO CABEZA LENTEJA METAL",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "AUTOPERFORANTE HEXAGONAL METAL",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "AUTOPERFORANTE HEXAGONAL CON GOLILLA TECHO METAL",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "CLAVO DISPARO POLVORA SDM HORMIGON",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "TORNILLO MADERA MUEBLES",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "TORNILLO PARA FIBROCEMENTO",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "ROSCALATA RANURA COMBINADA",
                                    "url": "/shop/catalog"
                                } 
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "ABRASIVOS",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "SOLDADURA",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "TECLE",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "BROCAS",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "MAQUINAS",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "UTILES",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "MANUALES",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": []
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "SOLDADORA",
                            "url": "/shop/catalog",
                            "items": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
```

he intentado hacer de varias forma pero aún no llego al resultado deseado he llegado a este resultado pero para los demás no logro insertar ese nivel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sí me pueden ayudar le agradezco

Esto es lo que he intentado this.menu es el array base

```
this.menu.forEach((resp,i)=>{

    let items:any={
        label:resp.marca, 
        url: '/shop/catalog', 
        menu: {
            type: 'megamenu',
            size: 'xl',
            image: 'assets/images/megamenu/megamenu-1.jpg',
             columns: [
                {
                 size: 3, 
                 items: []
                }
             ]
      
            
        }}
    menu1.push(items);  
  
    let res = this.menu.filter((menu)=> {
        return menu.marca === `${resp.marca}`;//${resp.marca}
    }).map( (menu)=> {
        return menu.lstSubmenu;
    })
    //  console.log("resFilter-->",res);  
 
  res.forEach((subMenu:any,x:any)=>{
    subMenu.forEach((element:any,z:any) => {
        // console.log("subMenu-->",element,"--Index-->",x);
            let sub:any ={
                label:  element.seccion ,
                url: '/shop/catalog', 
                items: []
            } 
         menu1[i].menu['columns'][x].items.push(sub)  
    }); 
    let res2 = subMenu.filter((menu:any)=> {
       
        return menu.seccion === `${subMenu[x].seccion}`;//${resp.marca}
    }).map( (menu:any)=> {
        return menu.lstSeccion;
    }) 
      res2.forEach((subMenu:any,y:any)=>{
        subMenu.forEach((element:any,z:any) => { 
            let sub:any ={
                label:  element.categoria ,
                url: '/shop/catalog',                             
        } 
        menu1[i].menu['columns'][x].items[y].items.push(sub) 
    });
   
      });

  }) 
});
```

Comment: Hola, podrías compartir las formas que has intentado?

Comment: Tampoco es muy claro exactamente que es lo que quieres insertar ni como estás  generando eso... por eso es importante que compartas el código para poder replicar el error o revisar donde estás fallando

Comment: ya comparti lo que he intentado hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor es usar [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) que es justamente para lo que sirve. En tu caso, son `map's` dentro de `map's`

Algo así:

```js
const datos = [
{
    "suma": 262.34190216330126,
    "marca": "SKAND",
    "lstSubmenu": [
        {
            "seccion": "TORNILLOS",
            "lstSeccion": [
                {
                    "categoria": "TORNILLO VOLCANITA CRS MADERA",
                    "suma": 37.41715341683438
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TORNILLO MADERA  ESTRUCTURAS (TURBO)",
                    "suma": 22.508639854731268
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TORNILLO VOLCANITA METAL",
                    "suma": 16.48031714561349
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "FULMINANTE VAINA ROJO AMARILLO CALIBRE .27",
                    "suma": 13.473193915399513
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "AUTOPERFORANTE TAPFAST TECHO MADERA",
                    "suma": 8.776999963607862
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TIRAFONDO HEXAGONAL MADERA",
                    "suma": 7.300000000000001
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TORNILLO CABEZA LENTEJA METAL",
                    "suma": 7.276133964067369
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "AUTOPERFORANTE HEXAGONAL METAL",
                    "suma": 7.045190446934608
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "AUTOPERFORANTE HEXAGONAL CON GOLILLA TECHO METAL",
                    "suma": 5.573167700273727
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "CLAVO DISPARO POLVORA SDM HORMIGON",
                    "suma": 1.5152119865873657
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TORNILLO MADERA MUEBLES",
                    "suma": 0.6049151332396524
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TORNILLO PARA FIBROCEMENTO",
                    "suma": 0.19929074105507238
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "ROSCALATA RANURA COMBINADA",
                    "suma": 0.046330078869591194
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TARUGO CLAVO HORMIGON",
                    "suma": 0.030332912614208018
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "GOLILLA PLANA",
                    "suma": 0.0033440822661030853
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "GOLILLA PRESION",
                    "suma": 0
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "PERNO HEXAGONAL GRADO 2 UNC - ISO 5.8 METRICO",
                    "suma": 0
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "PRODUCTOS CALZADOS                                ",
                    "suma": 0
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "CLAVO ACERO HORMIGON",
                    "suma": 0
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TARUGO HORMIGON",
                    "suma": 0
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TORNILLO PARA HERRAJES",
                    "suma": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seccion": "ABRASIVOS",
            "lstSeccion": [
                {
                    "categoria": "DISCO CORTE ACERO",
                    "suma": 33.85791067578473
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "DISCO TRASLAPADO ACERO",
                    "suma": 6.806285061196529
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "DISCO DESBASTE ACERO",
                    "suma": 5.906160259171886
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "DISCO CORTE CONCRETO",
                    "suma": 4.119951452256649
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "COPA CORTE CONCRETO",
                    "suma": 1.1727751112538822
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "DISCO CORTE CERAMICA",
                    "suma": 0.4903814350895895
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "DISCO FUNDICION ACERO",
                    "suma": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seccion": "SOLDADURA",
            "lstSeccion": [
                {
                    "categoria": "ALAMBRE MIG SOLIDO  E70S-6",
                    "suma": 22.943545314549496
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "ELECTRODO AWS E6011",
                    "suma": 10.279470901277177
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "ELECTRODO AWS E7018",
                    "suma": 6.1487509484998295
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "ALAMBRE MIG TUBULAR E71T-1",
                    "suma": 3.1778677999999996
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "ELECTRODO AWS E6010",
                    "suma": 1.65330998985258
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "seccion": "TECLE",
            "lstSeccion": [
                {
                    "categoria": "TIRACABLE-TIRFOR (Y-H)",
                    "suma": 8.970746389999999
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TECLE MANUAL CADENA HD (CHB)",
                    "suma": 4.592762842743909
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TECLE PALANCA CADENA HD (LHA)",
                    "suma": 3.754105505600121
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "GRILLETES",
                    "suma": 0.55551605
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "ESLINGAS PLANAS",
                    "suma": 0.21745942556541334
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "ESLINGAS TIRO AMARRE CARGAS",
                    "suma": 0
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "TECLE ELECTRICO CADENA 1AM (EHB)",
                    "suma": 0
                },
                {
                    "categoria": "CADENA CARGA-MANDO",
                    "suma": 0
                }
            ]
        }


    ]
},

];

var datos2 = datos.map(x => ({
label: x.marca,
url: "/shop/catalog",
menu: {
    type: "megamenu",
    size: "xl",
    image: "assets/images/megamenu/megamenu-1.jpg",
    columns: {
        size: 3, // esto es constante?
        items: x.lstSubmenu.map(c => ({
            label: c.seccion,
            url: "/shop/catalog",
            items: c.lstSeccion.map(s => ({
                label: s.categoria,
                url: "/shop/catalog"
            }))
        }))
        }
    }

}));

console.log(datos2);
```